# Lock vector element-wise

Tags: multithreading, locking, mutex

I'm reading a huge file (25m) record and I'm trying to speed that up. I've tried mmap and multithreaded reading. The problem is within each thread I've to write to the below structure which is not thread-safe. I've tried mutex but I've to lock up the whole vector which even makes reading slower. Is there any suggestions to make locking element-wise?

```
    vector<unsigned> *flight_passengers = new vector<unsigned>[1400000];
```